# Want to Print a Particular Number in Spacy Feature Extraction

Tags: python, spacy

In this Code, If I Want to Print a Particular Number What Should I do. Please Help Me With a Code,

**Output I Needed**

Numbers: ['1']

**Code**

```py
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
text = "Hello 1 2 3"
doc = nlp(text)
for token in doc:
    print(token, token.pos_)

print("Numbers:", [token.text for token in doc if token.pos_ == "NUM"])
```

**Output**

```
Hello INTJ
1 NUM
2 NUM
3 NUM
Numbers: ['1', '2', '3']
```

Answer (score 1):

You may get the first item only using list slicing:

```py
>>> print("Numbers:", [token.text for token in doc if token.pos_ == "NUM"][:1])
Numbers: ['1']
```